# Using withTickedStroke from matplotlib.patheffects for feasible regions

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour

I've been trying to run the [demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contours_in_optimization_demo.html) for contouring optimization problems solutions in matplotlib, but `patheffects` doesn't have the same attributes as the ones stated in the link.

The code of the demo is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import patheffects

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))

nx = 101
ny = 105

# Set up survey vectors
xvec = np.linspace(0.001, 4.0, nx)
yvec = np.linspace(0.001, 4.0, ny)

# Set up survey matrices.  Design disk loading and gear ratio.
x1, x2 = np.meshgrid(xvec, yvec)

# Evaluate some stuff to plot
obj = x1**2 + x2**2 - 2*x1 - 2*x2 + 2
g1 = -(3*x1 + x2 - 5.5)
g2 = -(x1 + 2*x2 - 4.5)
g3 = 0.8 + x1**-3 - x2

cntr = ax.contour(x1, x2, obj, [0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16],
                  colors='black')
ax.clabel(cntr, fmt="%2.1f", use_clabeltext=True)

cg1 = ax.contour(x1, x2, g1, [0], colors='sandybrown')
plt.setp(cg1.collections,
         path_effects=[patheffects.withTickedStroke(angle=135)])

cg2 = ax.contour(x1, x2, g2, [0], colors='orangered')
plt.setp(cg2.collections,
         path_effects=[patheffects.withTickedStroke(angle=60, length=2)])

cg3 = ax.contour(x1, x2, g3, [0], colors='mediumblue')
plt.setp(cg3.collections,
         path_effects=[patheffects.withTickedStroke(spacing=7)])

ax.set_xlim(0, 4)
ax.set_ylim(0, 4)

plt.show()
```

I expected to get this plot:

[image: Resulting plot]

but the following error arised instead,

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.patheffects' has no attribute 'withTickedStroke'

Searching in the source code some version of TickedStroke exists, but aren't accesible directly as an attribute of patheffects and I can't get them to work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the last version of matplotlib (or at least 3.4). You version is too old (matplotlib < 3.4):

```
>>> pip install -U matplotlib
```

Before 3.4:

```
...
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.patheffects' has no attribute 'withTickedStroke'
```

After 3.4:

[image]

Comment: If they're using anaconda, this will potentially fubar their environment. With anaconda it should be `conda update matplotlib`, or better `conda update --all`, for updating the `(base)` environment.